# Debian 9 and 10 is not installing bootloader on removable device

Tags: debian, boot-loader, debian-installer

I am new to linux, I have installed Manjaro and Lubuntu on partition `sda9` of my hard drive without any issues. I always installed the bootloader to a removable device (`sdc`).

I downloaded the Debian live iso. I can boot the live version without problems, and also install Debian on a hard drive with the bootloader installed to the hard drive, and no issues.

I need to install the bootloader to a removable device... but Debian is not doing it at all. When the installation finishes, the removable device to boot the system is blank!

My assumption is that it can be also done by using the live Debian to install the bootloader, but don't know the commands. Need help!

Debian is installed on partition `sda9`.  Swap partition is `sda10`.

Comment: So is in 9 or 10? Which one. Debian 10 “Buster”, was released on Saturday. Is it this one?

Comment: The issue of the bootloader not installing happens with both 9 and 10; I deleted the Debian 9 ISO, so I will be using Debian 10.(I downloaded the Debian "Live" ISO that includes the installer).